# Using separate a webserver for cronjobs, also: MySQL concurrent connections from 2 different servers

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I have developed a web application that would really benefit from cronjobs that run certain php scripts in a scheduled manner.

As some scripts should run every let's say 15 seconds I would like to have a little server instance that just does those cronjob tasks.

Is this a good idea? And can MySQL handle those parallel connections from 2 different servers?

Comment: MySQL can handle parallell connections (regardless from where these originate), but a problem can occur if concurrrent writes are done.

Comment: What does "concurrent writes" mean here? When scripts from both servers want to change the same fields for example? This is nothing I would have in my code structure.

Comment: I would have something like this: A user registers and his email is written into a table. Then the cronjob reads the mail from the table, tries to send the mail and when it succeeds it would delete this entry from the table.

Comment: just a suggestion .. why not send the email on trigger of registration ?

Comment: I have read that sending mails can be a bit tricky as sometimes it takes longer than expected or it could fail. I don't want the user to wait for the mail being send. Or can you say that this is absolutely no problem? I am using Amazon SES for email sending.

Comment: And if not for the registration I would still like to have some ways to move possibly heavy tasks like account deletion into night time when the server is not busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very good idea.

Regardless of if connections are local or remote from multiple servers, databases are designed to handle lots of simultaneous connections. By default, [MySQL can handle 151 connections](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections), but you can set this to a much higher value if needed (assuming the server can handle it).

I always set up my database(s) on a separate server from the web server (i.e. the public facing server running PHP). On larger apps I've worked on in the past, we had multiple web servers behind a load balancer that all went to the same database server and never had any issues.

There are many advantages to having separate servers dedicated to specific tasks and I could spend all night writing about them, but here's are some highlights:

- Separate servers allow you to optimize each server's resources for the specific task it needs to perform (i.e. memory usage, disk I/O, etc.)
- Security, Security, Security!

  - If you have crons performing sensitive jobs such as deleting an account, you don't want them living on a public facing server that is more likely to be compromised.
  - You can create a separate privileged user only allowed to connect from your cron server (i.e. the crons need to drop and create tables, but your web app only needs CRUD privileges)
- It's much easier to manage each task

  - If you need to pause all cron jobs, simply take the server down instead of having to comment out each cron job.

Comment: Thanks for this really sophisticated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is good idea to separate out cron jobs.

1. You can run this crons on small server all you need php installed.
2. Mysql can handle many connections from different hosts.
3. Run the php scripts from the command line for faster execution.